# Cannot run the program on the command prompt but can in IPython

Tags: python, batch-file, ipython, dos

I have written a program:

```
import pylab as pl 
import numpy as np
from random import random


pl.figure()

r = np.array([ random() - 0.5 for xx in range(1000) ])

for i in range(20):
    print i
    pl.clf()
    pl.hist(r, 50)
    pl.savefig( 'abc%04d.png'%i )
    r += np.array([ random() - 0.5 for xx in range(1000) ])
    pl.show()
```

which works fine of I run in iPython. However, if I do a

```
C:\> python test.py
```

on the command prompt, I have to close the figure each time for getting the output. Anyone knows how to solve this problem? Eventually I want to write a batch file which someone can doubleclick to run the file.

Comment: you can remove the `pl.show()`

Comment: What is it that you would like to happen when someone runs the file? Save your graphs to disk?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Yes. Just save all the pictures in one place. The above is a contrived program illustrating the problem I am facing in a code which is much more involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IPython kernel has specific hooks for working with interactive graphics, which the standard Python interpreter doesn't. This is explained in more detail (with a couple of workarounds) on [this page](http://matplotlib.org/users/shell.html),

Answer (score 2):

As @monkut remarked, you should remove `p1.show()`.

The show() command in your code stops until the figure is closed. This is discussed here:

http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#use-show

It depends on if the script is running in non-interactive mode (the default) or interactive mode. And in interactive mode it'll show all the figures at once. Not very useful either!

So you need to add some kind of event (keyboard or timer) which refreshes the plot. The above page shows many variants.